# dialog background image with arrow using same background

Tags: css, facebook, background

I am making a facebook app and to keep with the facebook design flow within the iframe, I am "copying" some of the facebook features. The one I am having trouble with is the hover card popup dialog with the arrow using the parent background image.

In the link below, you will see what I am trying to do.
http://grab.by/k9Na

In that pic, I am using 2 absolute divs with the same position properties. The first layer has a transparent background image with an inverted white arrow (same color as background). The second layer is set to the cover photo, and is overlapped by the first layer giving it the arrow look.

I am having trouble getting the correct position of the cover photo into the second arrow layer. I tried searching this for a while came up empty. I inspected facebooks code as well and got even more confused.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It may not be the best or most efficient solution but it works.

http://grab.by/kapw

In the pic above, you will see I mapped out 3 blue boxes (divs). These boxes are placed inside an absolute container with the same width as the dialog popup and a fixed height of 15px.

The 3 boxes are positioned based on which face box is being hovered above container. In this example, the 2nd box from left is being hovered - notice the arrow is pointing towards it.

Set the '**left**' div width to the face box left position.

Set the '**bg**' div left position to the face box left position.

Set the '**right**' div left position to the sum of the left and bg div widths.

Set the '**right**' div width to the parent width subtracting the sum of the left and bg widths.

Set the zIndex of the div **container** to a high number.

Place a *transparent inversed arrow* inside the **bg** div inner html

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="bg">
   <img src="inversedArrow.png">
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
 </div>
```

Viola!